Receipt scanner that requires NOTHING from me other than inserting/removing the receipt
I'm looking for a receipt scanner that I can use as follows:

Arrive home from shopping

Easily feed my receipt into it

I retrieve the files somehow periodically every few months

The scanner does NOT require a network connection to be usable like this.


That's it. Literally no other phones/computers/devices or fuss must be involved until I decide to retrieve the files months later.
I don't want to pull up a computer/phone/etc. every time just to verify the scan was done correctly, otherwise that it will defeat the point. So this means I need some way to sanity check the scan on the device itself.
Does such a device exist?

To be honest, if you have a printer already then it can do this for free. Usually will allow you to scan to your USB stick.
But if you're looking to buy, then buy the cheapest printer with scanner that you can. Usually these will be MFP printers, and you can even buy them second hand. Always check the specs to ensure it allows "scan to usb"

(a) An MFP printer is goddamn huge, I want something tiny. (b) Feeding a receipt into a scanner that takes 8.5"-wide sheets of paper is an excruciating exercise, it'll come out crooked all the time. Also their feeders often don't work on tiny receipts. (c) For most printers you have to press a bunch of buttons to get it to start scanning in the first place, I just want to insert the receipt without doing anything else. (d) When I say "receipt scanner" I mean something that has the usual features of a receipt scanner, like OCR & attempts to detect something useful on the receipt...

I said "usually". You can use your mobile phone as a scanner instead, just install the Genius scan app and that will do it.

Pulling out a phone, starting an app, holding up the receipt, taking a picture, realizing the receipt was bent, doing it again, etc. are incredibly painful to do on a daily basis. You missed the entire point of the question...
